# AWS Lambda: Is max memory used always in MB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

In CloudWatch logs for AWS Lambda, there are lines like this:

`REPORT RequestId: 8b4a32a4-7dc0-4342-a998-48b051d683e0 Duration: 182.29 ms Billed Duration: 200 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 35 MB`

Is it safe to assume the Max Memory Used will always be logged in MB? I can't find anything to confirm either way, and any sort of dashboard seems to use structured data that is definitely in megabytes, but I doubt that information is scraped from logs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just tried running an AWS Lambda function with maximum memory allocation and it returned:

> Duration: 1.41 ms  Billed Duration: 100 ms **Memory Size: 3008 MB**    Max Memory Used: 59 MB  Init Duration: 107.64 ms

While that isn't a test of the `Max Memory` field, the `Memory Size` field does show MB, so it would be fair to assume that `Max Memory` would do the same even at large values.

Comment: In my case, the memory error was caused because the external database was not allowing the Serverless IP to make requests to the database and the resolver was exceeding the timeout, [reference](https://forum.serverless.com/t/task-timed-out-after-6-00-seconds/728) to change the timeout... even though there was a huge amount of free memory